# results not valid after appending one pickle file to another in append binary mode

Tags: python, pickle, face-recognition

I have a main pickle file for my dataset and every few time i also have a new pickle file for some new data so i want to append the newly generated pickle file to the main pickle file. The results are not accurate if i use append this way

```
with open('new_pickle', 'rb') as f:
               encoded = pickle.load(f)
with open("encodings.pickle",'ab+') as outfile:
               pickle.dump(encoded,outfile)
```

What I tried but not satisfied because the write mode is not what i want . I need to do this via append mode so that the new results should add to the main pickle i.e encodings.pickle:

```
with open("encodings.pickle", 'rb') as fa:
               encoded1 = pickle.load(fa)
with open('encodings_backup.pickle', 'wb') as fa:
               pickle.dump(encoded1,fa)
with open('new_pickle', 'rb') as f:
               encoded = pickle.load(f)
encoded1.update(encoded)

with open("encodings.pickle",'wb') as outfile:
           pickle.dump(encoded1,outfile)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't concatenate pickle files together. You might be better off with a different serialization format, such as [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/). Also consider storing your data in a database.

Comment: I don’t understand the variety of filenames here—can you simplify the example if possible or add annotations otherwise?

Comment: @DavisHerring updated. I am just having a backup of my main pickle file 'encodings.pickle'. and then updating the main file.

Comment: @zaheerabbas: So… are you reading multiple times from (one opening of!) your concatenated pickle?

Comment: @DavisHerring no right now i am getting data from multiple sources at single time and want to append that

Comment: @zaheerabbas: I’m asking how you (will) read the result; that determines how you should write it.